# How Deserialize JSON with escape characters

Tags: c#, json, webclient

if I check `url` in a browser get:

```
{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}
```

So that JSON has two element "status" and "value"

Following the example below. When I `DeserializeObject(text)` data.Count return 3

But `wc.DownloadString(url)` return:

```
"{\"status\":{\"message\":\"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.\",\"value\":18}}"
```

And after `DeserializeObject(json)`  data.Count return null.

I try:

```
json = json.Replace(@"\", "");
```

But "\" arent removed, and also I dont want to strip any "\" on the original JSON.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static string url = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=-68,1&lng=10,2&username=demo";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var text = @"[{'Name':'AAA','Age':'22','Job':'PPP'},
                {'Name':'BBB','Age':'25','Job':'QQQ'},
                {'Name':'CCC','Age':'38','Job':'RRR'}]";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text); 
            // data.Count = 3


            data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            // data.Count = null
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Even when duplicate question show why the display in debugger is different to the text display, the problem is the `DeserializeObject` isnt working

Comment: That's just you inspecting the value, it doesn't really have those escape characters in it. It's an annoying oddity of visual studio.

Comment: `text` represents an array with 3 elements, why wouldn't `Count` be 3 then? The web service you're calling returns an `Object` with a single property ("status"), hence rightfully `Count` is 1

Comment: @haim770 `Deserialize(text)` return a 3 elements array. `Deserialize(json)` count return null.

Comment: @mattmanser The problem is Deserialize doesnt return a two element array, so can't access the values inside.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, If you'll treat your `data` as `JObject` (as it really is), you'll get to the proper `Count` property.

Comment: @haim770 I need more info. You mean use `JObject data = ...` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Yes. Or create your own type to represent the data, then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>()`.

Comment: I guess since `Count` is defined on the base `JContainer` type, the DLR (since you're using `dynamic`) can't access it. Anyway, it doesn't seem like your problem is the slashes, but more with the usage of `dynamic` runtime binding.